# How to see data while hovering over a point in a R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to add a "hover" features that shows the name of the country plotted in a symbols plot in an R Shiny app. Most of the guidance on the internet is for ggplot. Can "hover" be added to a regular symbols plot?

```
    output$info <- renderText({
≠paste0("Country =", input$plot_click)
})
```

This is what I have after my symbols plots in the server section of my code. However, it does not bring up the country name though.

Comment: ggplot does not have such interactive capabilities. `plotly` does, though, so you will have to look into that!

Comment: You can check `ggiraph`. It providdes tooltips for a `ggplot`.

Answer (score 2):

Your example might refer to [Interactive plots](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html), you can refer to `shiny::runGitHub('shiny-examples/118-highcharter-births/')`.

[image: shiny-examples/118-highcharter-births]